# Apache init.d script

Tags: service, debian, init.d

I have the following script to start, stop, restart apache2 in my debian 7

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          apache2
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: apache2
# Description: Start apache2
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
start)
        echo "Starting Apache ..."
        # Change the location to your specific location
        /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
;;
stop)
        echo "Stopping Apache ..."
        # Change the location to your specific location
        /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop
;;
graceful)
        echo "Restarting Apache gracefully..."
        # Change the location to your specific location
        /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl graceful
;;
restart)
        echo "Restarting Apache ..."
        # Change the location to your specific location
        /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart
;;
*)
        echo "Usage: '$0' {start|stop|restart|graceful}"
        exit 64
;;
esac
exit 0
```

When I add the script to update-rc.d I see the following warnings:

```
root@pomelo:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d apache2 defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: Script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `jexec'
```

But I already added Required-Stop and Default-Stop to the script.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in your apache2 init script, it is in 'jexec' it says so 'Script jexec is broken'.

That one is missing the Required-Stop and Default-Stop

Had the same issue on my SLES boxen. Don't worry though, even if it shows you these errors, everything still just runs fine!

HTH